# Обеспечивает ли QSqlQuery::bindValue защиту от SQL-инъекций?

Tags: qt

Вот пример кода из документации Qt:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname) "
              "VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)");
query.bindValue(":id", 1001);
query.bindValue(":forename", "Bart");
query.bindValue(":surname", "Simpson");
query.exec();
```

Нужно ли предпринимать дополнительные меры по фильтрации значений, которые передаются в метод bindValue, для защиты от sql-инъекции или Qt и/или сервер (PostgreSQL) сделают всё, что нужно сами? В [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html) про это ничего не сказано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Большинство современных движков баз данных уже не обрабатывает запросы так, как это делалось в классическом php, когда весь запрос собирался и уже готовый отправлялся базе. Все работает немного по другому. Базе отправляется запрос с параметрами (да, так как Вы его написали - с двоеточиями, правда некоторые движки хотят запись с знаками вопросов вместо параметров, но Qt это красиво скрывает и позволяет обе записи). А потом, базе отправляется словарь (список пар ключ-значение). Это сильно упрощает разбор длинных выражений и естественно убирает все возможности для инъекций в базу.

Но это не защищает от других инъекций - когда значения, сохраненные в базе используются для вывода пользователю, например, на html страницу.

Comment: Да, здесь с двоеточиями, а на C# используется символ '@'.